# R data.table lapply not summing to group level when using `:=`

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to summarize multiple columns in a data.table. I want to use `:=` to update the object in memory for performance. But the result doesn't seem to be summing to the group level.

Here is the code to produce the problem:

```
library(data.table)

test <- data.table(RISKID = c("AH3A7440560010", "AH3A7440560010", "AHV91366770317",
                              "AHV91366770317", "AW291803540211", "AW291803540211", 
                              "AWDA3942720114", "AWDA3942720114", "AWE90323940610", 
                              "AWE90323940610", "AWE90323940610", "AWF93153630052",
                              "AWF93153630052", "AWP88472020710", "AWP88472020710",
                              "AWXA2198130111", "AWXA2198130111", "AWXA2198130111", 
                              "AWY53043500212", "AWY53043500212", "AWYA2607300210", "AWYA2607300210"),
                   COLILPIT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23090.52, 0),
                   COLEX = c(12, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 0, 6.74, 1.94, 11.9, 0.0999999999999996, 0,
                             8.05, 0, 7.73, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0),
                   CMPILPIT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 86.18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                   CMPEX = c(12, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 0, 6.74, 1.94, 11.9, 0.0999999999999996, 0,
                             8.05, 4.11, 0, 3.62, 12, 0, 12, 0), 
                   BIILPIT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                   BIEX = c(12,0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 0, 6.74, 1.94, 11.9, 0.0999999999999996, 0, 8.05,
                            0, 7.73, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0),
                   PDILPIT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 487.57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                   PDEX = c(12, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 0, 6.74, 1.94, 11.9, 0.0999999999999996, 
                            0, 8.05, 0, 7.73, 0, 12, 0, 12, 0))

cols <- grep('IL|EX', names(test), value = TRUE)
```

```
> test[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = 'RISKID', .SDcols = cols]
            RISKID COLILPIT COLEX CMPILPIT CMPEX BIILPIT  BIEX PDILPIT  PDEX
 1: AH3A7440560010     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 2: AHV91366770317     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 3: AW291803540211     0.00 12.00    86.18 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 4: AWDA3942720114     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00  487.57 12.00
 5: AWE90323940610     0.00  8.68     0.00  8.68       0  8.68    0.00  8.68
 6: AWF93153630052     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 7: AWP88472020710     0.00  8.05     0.00  8.05       0  8.05    0.00  8.05
 8: AWXA2198130111     0.00  7.73     0.00  7.73       0  7.73    0.00  7.73
 9: AWY53043500212     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
10: AWYA2607300210 23090.52 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
```

```
test2 <- copy(test)
test2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, sum), by = 'RISKID', .SDcols = cols][]
```

```
> test2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, sum), by = 'RISKID', .SDcols = cols][]
            RISKID COLILPIT COLEX CMPILPIT CMPEX BIILPIT  BIEX PDILPIT  PDEX
 1: AH3A7440560010     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 2: AH3A7440560010     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 3: AHV91366770317     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 4: AHV91366770317     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 5: AW291803540211     0.00 12.00    86.18 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 6: AW291803540211     0.00 12.00    86.18 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
 7: AWDA3942720114     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00  487.57 12.00
 8: AWDA3942720114     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00  487.57 12.00
 9: AWE90323940610     0.00  8.68     0.00  8.68       0  8.68    0.00  8.68
10: AWE90323940610     0.00  8.68     0.00  8.68       0  8.68    0.00  8.68
11: AWE90323940610     0.00  8.68     0.00  8.68       0  8.68    0.00  8.68
12: AWF93153630052     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
13: AWF93153630052     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
14: AWP88472020710     0.00  8.05     0.00  8.05       0  8.05    0.00  8.05
15: AWP88472020710     0.00  8.05     0.00  8.05       0  8.05    0.00  8.05
16: AWXA2198130111     0.00  7.73     0.00  7.73       0  7.73    0.00  7.73
17: AWXA2198130111     0.00  7.73     0.00  7.73       0  7.73    0.00  7.73
18: AWXA2198130111     0.00  7.73     0.00  7.73       0  7.73    0.00  7.73
19: AWY53043500212     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
20: AWY53043500212     0.00 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
21: AWYA2607300210 23090.52 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
22: AWYA2607300210 23090.52 12.00     0.00 12.00       0 12.00    0.00 12.00
            RISKID COLILPIT COLEX CMPILPIT CMPEX BIILPIT  BIEX PDILPIT  PDEX
```

The test data.table returns the correct sum by `RISKID`, but when I add `:=` to update the columns in place, the columns were not summarized to the `RISKID` level. I have been using data.table for a few years and this surprised me a little because I have used the same code before without encountering this problem.

Comment: Are you sure this worked before? It seems to me this is correct behaviour, `:=` is supposed to work on columns, so in this case it's updating the columns with the aggregation.

Comment: agree with @josemz, I think you just need `test <- test[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = 'RISKID', .SDcols = cols]`

Comment: OK, but wouldn't that be ineffecient because it involves copying the whole object?

Comment: It's aggregating the object to a different one with fewer rows, so a copy is necessary. The "modify in place" functionality only works for transformations that maintain the set of rows, currently.